# Visual Studio 2012 RTM intellisense: fix for "hang/pause"?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've just installed the Visual Studio 2012 RTM on a Windows 7 x64 desktop.

Unfortunately, I'm very underwelmed by the performance of the out-of-the-box installation.  Everytime I try to rename a file in the solution explorer, change to a MVC cshtml editor, open a designer view, or intellisense pops up when I start typing with the c# editor, the whole visual studio applications hangs for 5-10 seconds.

There are no customizations, plugins, extensions enabled here that do not get applied with the standard installation.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Has anyone else found a way to log the application faults which occur, or detect the hang.  I need some way to determine what is going wrong, in order to identify what needs to be altered to rectify the installation.

Comment: Not experienced this myself; been using 2012 a lot the past week. (Win7x64 here, too). I would say to check your extensions, but... ehhh.

Comment: I agree with the OP.  I do not have any extensions running and VS2012 constantly hangs.  And seeing that I have an Intel i7 Extreme and 12GB of RAM I don't see how this could be a resources issue.  (If it is Microsoft really needs to fire their dev team and find people that know how to program efficiently.)

Comment: Mine didn't do this initially, but working with an asp.net project it freezes every time i rename a file. Sometimes I spam-click close to bring up the "application is not responding" popup, where I can then click "recover this application" and it actually recovers instantly. But patience also works :)

Answer (score -7):

The problem is you are consuming the lot more resources of the system which is causing hung state of VS. Please close any of other application who is using more RAM. You can take the help of Task Manager to close those application. Please keep in mind if you are running SQL standalone database instance services then its also causes the hand issue. The best is keep you system free from running unuseful application or Go for System upgrade. :-)

Comment: The biggest use of resources on my machine is visual studio 2012.  It looks like it has some sort of a resource leak/sink.